# Trying to order a 3 table JOIN by date desc, How to sort correctly?

Tags: php, mysqli

Have 3 different mysql tables, my script queries the DB using JOINS to output the most recent results from each of the 3 tables. All works like it is supposed to but the way mysql databases allow for JOINS, the ORDER BY will order the results as you list the tables, resulting in the finished output not being ordered by date correctly, since the results are from 3 different MYSQL tables.

The results instead are ordered by date correctly only next to the other results form the same table. See the script and results below: (I am limit 1 for the output for simplicity)

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$result = $mysqli->query("
SELECT 
    accounts.account_name, 
    cases.case_subject, 
    tasks.task_title,
    accounts.accounts_date_last_edited, 
    cases.cases_date_last_edited, 
    tasks.tasks_date_last_edited
FROM 
    accounts, 
    cases, 
    tasks 
 WHERE 
    accounts.username = cases.username 
    AND cases.username = tasks.username 
 ORDER BY 
    accounts.accounts_date_last_edited DESC,
    cases.cases_date_last_edited DESC, 
    tasks.tasks_date_last_edited DESC 
 LIMIT 1
");

if (!$result) { echo "Error Result5: " . $mysqli->error; } else {

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Item</th><th>Date</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['account_name'] . "</td><br>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['accounts_date_last_edited'] . "</td><br>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['case_subject'] . "</td><br>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['cases_date_last_edited'] . "</td><br>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['task_title'] . "</td><br>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['tasks_date_last_edited'] . "</td><br>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The Results are below: they will list 1 item from each table listed above. Again I am trying to sort by the date_last_edited regardless of which table the values are from.

```
Item                           Date

Shorley Homes                  2013-11-02 04:02:34 
Techical Testing Case Open     2013-11-03 07:17:36
Icons                          2013-11-03 07:28:02
```

Comment: It appears to be because you are not actually `JOIN`ing the tables.

Comment: @micahbf The joins are done using ANSI89, not ANSI92. Nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: @JohnConde Ahhhh, I just formatted the query to be readable!

Comment: @Fluffeh Looks like our edits collided. I re-added your edit for our reading pleasure. :)

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks, your edit I think was more thorough, I was interested in seeing the query in a readable state (was thinking the problem might be there). Good show in any case :)

Comment: What I need is a way to sort through the array results, maybe a way to structure as multidimensional array than can use a usort or uasort, but not sure how to put the output into the correct format to use uasort etc. does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read correctly (and I'm not sure of that) your

> ...sort by the `date_last_edited` **regardless** of which table the values are from...

then you might want to use `UNION` instead of `JOIN`

```sql
SELECT account_name item, accounts_date_last_edited date
  FROM accounts
UNION ALL
SELECT case_subject, cases_date_last_edited
  FROM cases
UNION ALL
SELECT task_title, tasks_date_last_edited
  FROM tasks
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1105b/1)** demo